# Apache Zeppelin-Highcharts displaying blank output

Tags: highcharts, apache-zeppelin, drilldown

I configured HighCharts on our Zeppelin Tool to implement a drill down functionality.
We placed the below jar files and stated the same in the Dependencies

- Zeppelin-highcharts-0.6.4.jar
- lift-json_2.11-2.6.3.jar
- paranamer-2.4.1.jar

We tried executing the below code-

---

```
val bank = spark.read.option("header",true).csv("/u01/zepplin/bank/bank2.csv")
bank.show()
```

+---+-------+
|age|balance|
+---+-------+
| 20|  40000|
| 30|  60000|
| 50|  70000|
| 80|  90000|
+---+-------+

---

```
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._
highcharts(bank.series("x" -> "age", "y" -> sum(col("balance"))).orderBy(col("age"))).plot()
```

But this code is not able to plot anything, giving a blank out put.It just shows the tile(Chart Title).
To rule out the browser compatibility issue I tried this on all the browsers too.
Am I missing something here.Do we have any alternative for High-charts for custom visualization like drill down etc.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think that the higher probability of getting help with your issue you can get from the Apache wrapper creator - https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sebastian

Comment: @Rockie Yang can you please help me to resolve the posted issue

Comment: I mean, try here: https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts/issues